# Why is this framebuffer incomplete? (EXT_framebuffer_object)

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

This code works on my fancy, semi-new Nvidia computer, but the framebuffer is incomplete when run with an Intel GPU with drivers that are probably a few years old:

```
GLuint fbo = 0;
glGenFramebuffersEXT( 1, &fbo );

GLuint tex = 0;
glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 320, 240, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

glBindFramebufferEXT( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo );
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0 );

GLenum attachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT;
glDrawBuffers( 1, &attachment );

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT );
// status is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER_EXT
```

The Intel one apparently supports this extension (**GLEW_EXT_framebuffer_object** is **true**). Its version string is "2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2086".

Is it a driver bug, or am I doing something wrong? What can I do about it other than tell people to update their drivers or buy something better?

Comment: Try using `GL_RGBA` for the format instead of `GL_RGB`. Even though `GL_RGB` is listed as a renderable format in the spec, rendering to RGB formats is not as well supported as rendering to RGBA formats.

Comment: @Reto I can give that a try, but maybe I should mention that I created other textures/FBOs which also use GL_RGB and they were complete.